# NSTimer "target": How to reference a method of a class?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm trying to wrap my head around Swift. Currently I don't understand how this piece of code should work:

```
backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: GameViewController(), selector: "addNext", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This statement crashes the game with

```
MyApp.GameViewController addNext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1cd0b0'
```

Basically I have a method in GameViewController class that I would like to call from all scenes with a timer. How can I reference gameViewController.addNext()? Basically what should I put in `"target"` ?

Here's the `GameViewController` and `addNext()` method:

```
 class GameViewController: GAITrackedViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate  {
   ...
      func addNext() {
        ...
      }
 }
```

Comment: can u show ur add next method

Comment: The new created instance of `GameViewController` is certainly not that one designed in the storyboard. Apart from that you can't create a *real working* UIViewController instance with the default initializer.

Comment: In Swift 2.2 you don't use strings as selectors, there is a new syntax which will prevent this kind of errors.

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of `addNext`?

Comment: @Sulthan the syntax to use strings as selectors is marked as deprecated in Swift 2.2 but is still fully operational and not the reason of that issue

Comment: addNext should not be private, or you can add @objc mark for the private method.

Comment: @Sulthan  Added addNext method.  I must add that I would like to make a reference to the instance of myapp's viewcontroller, not a temporary viewcontroller.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Added addNext method. I must add that I would like to make a reference to the instance of myapp's viewcontroller, not a temporary viewcontroller.

Comment: You have to keep that  `GameViewController` alive in some variable, otherwise it gets deallocated.

Comment: @Sulthan ok, I have a config class to where I created variable for my instance of gameViewController. However I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `GameViewController()` for the `target`, Swift creates a temporary instance of `GameViewController`, and gives it to `NSTimer` as the target for the `addNext` call. This is most certainly *not* what you want: you need a call to be made on the instance of your view controller, not on some temporary instance.

If you make timer registration from a method of `GameViewController`, say, from `viewDidLoad`, then you can pass `self` for the `target` parameter:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
        3
    ,   target: self
    ,   selector: #selector(GameViewController.addNext)
    ,   userInfo: nil
    ,   repeats: true
    )
}
```